# primeng : Dynamic load of p-tabPanel

Tags: angular, primeng

The goal of the following HTML+ts code:
Upon opening a configuration file, display XXX p-tabPanel in a p-tabView.
The number XXX is taken from the file.
**It works.** 
But in the loop over those panels, for each panel I want to call a method which is a member is the class of this p-tabPanel.
But at this stage, the object of the panel is not defined yet. There is a race condition.
How can I "delay" this till the object is defined ?

```js
export class DirectFindComponent implements OnInit {

  nofPages : number;
  pageTitle : string;
  items : number[];
  pages : PageComponent[];

  constructor(private waveform: WaveformService) { 
      this.nofPages = 0;
      this.pageTitle = 'Page';
  }

  public Load
  {
      //Upon file load, this.nofPages gets a value
      this.items = new Array (this.nofPages);
      for (let i=0;i<this.nofPages;i++)
      {
        //This is not working. At this stage, Pages[i] is not defined yet. There is a race condition here
        this.Pages[i].Load ();
      }
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

```html
<div >
    <p-tabView [styleClass]="'main'">
        <p-tabPanel [header]='pageTitle+i' *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [selected]="i == 0">
            <app-page [parent]="this" [id]="i" ></app-page>
        </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you ever set `Pages`?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with the following ts code:

```js
 for (let i=0;i<this.nofPages;i++)
{
  (async() => {
          while(this.pages[i]==undefined)
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1));
          console.log (this.pages[i]);
        })();
}
```

Not sure this is the right solution.

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: This is not the way to go. I commented on your question asking for details that are needed to answer it properly